# Return a Comma-Separated List from an Array Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I could probably puzzle this one out in VBA, but would rather not have to use that approach if possible, and it seems like this is something Excel's built-in functions should be able to manage.

I have a spreadsheet we recently stopped printing that we would use to verify data came in from our various sites, and for which days. Column headers correspond to site numbers ($D$1:$AU$1 for this spreadsheet) and rows are for dates ($A$3:$A$24 for the month of December -- we don't do this data validation on weekends). The "B" column contains the date whose information SHOULD have come in, for example, on 12/4, we should receive the information from 12/2 at each site.

In the past, we used column "C" to write which sites were behind. If Site 3 only sent in information from 12/1 on the 4th, we would write a "3" in that column. I'd like to continue this convention, since it's what the office understands. Change Is Bad and all that.

So far I've muddled through on my own and wrote an Array Formula that returns `{0,0,1,0,...,0}` if only site 3 is behind. That formula is `=IFERROR(SEARCH(B3,D3:AU3)-SEARCH(B3,D3:AU3),1)`

From here it's trivial to do `=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"",INDEX(D1:AU1,1,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(B3,D3:AU3)-SEARCH(B3,D3:AU3),1)),0))` which works great, so long as there's only one site that's behind. If we have more than one site behind, it returns the first value (as expected).

If both sites 3 and 6 are behind, we want to see "3, 6" (or any other human-readable format) but the only solutions I found are to write a custom VBA script to concat an array. I'd rather stay away from custom VBA if humanly possible.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: VBA might be best - there's no inbuilt worksheet function in excel that can concatenate an array - you could write a formula that would get 3 in one cell then 6 in another etc. would that help?

Comment: Not sure it would, since the number of sites that are "behind" could be zero one day and twelve the next. It's hard to account for variable columns in that way.

Comment: If you have the columns available you can write a formula that you can copy across 5 or 10 or 15 rows, as many as the maximum you might need - if there are no matches all the columns will display as blanks but if there are 7 behind or 1 you will get just those 7 or 1

Comment: You are using SEARCH in `SEARCH(B3,D3:AU3)` - use of SEARCH implies that B3 isn't an exact match - is that right? - if B3 contains a date don't you just expect an exact match somewhere in D3:AU3 (I.e. the same date?)

Comment: I may be able to add hidden columns after the data to pull that info to, then `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(<each>," ",<of>," ",<them>))` that way. That might help....

Comment: The worksheet is for December. B3 contains a number "28", for the 28th of last month. We can receive several day's info at once from a site, so (for example) site 1 (which is D3) contains "28-29-30". Needed to use SEARCH to make sure that exact value is found. I anticipate issues when we roll over into the new month (e.g. on 12/4 when we expect 12/2) if a store is so far behind they're just sending in the 29th, it'll match that "2," but it seems unlikely and human-fixable.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer that contains an array formula you can use in BA3 copied across (change that column as required) then you can get all the results and concatenate back to C3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this "array formula" in BA3

`=IFERROR(INDEX($D1:$AU1,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($B3,$D3:$AU3)),COLUMN($D3:$AU3)-COLUMN($D3)+1),COLUMNS($BA3:BA3))),"")`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy across to get all matches

As you say you can then concatenate those back to C3

Comment: This is working as intended, but only filters based on sites that DO have their data in on time. We're looking for the `#VALUE!` response from the `SEARCH` array.

Comment: D'oh!, yeah, I knew that but forgot......just change `ISNUMBER` in the middle to `ISERROR` (Note: not IFERROR) - I'll edit my answer

Comment: Perfect! I came up with my own solution in the meantime but this one is much prettier. I simply used `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH($B$4,D4:AU4)-SEARCH($B$4,D4:AU4),D1)=0,"",D1)` and autofilled one column for each site, then `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(BA3," ",BB3," ",BC3," ",...," ",CM3) IN B3.

Truly great work there, and I greatly appreciate it!