# Excel: Return all column headers with a value in the current row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 20+ columns and I'm trying to get on each row a list of the columns that are populated. For example:

```
Owner     Item List            Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
Me        Item1,Item2           3      4        
You       Item1,Item3,Item4     2            1     2
Her       Item2,Item3                  1     1  
Him       Item1,Item4           5                  6
```

For the "Me" row, `Item1` and `Item2` are populated, so the Item List is `"Item1,Item2"` (any delimiter is fine).

Is it possible to accomplish this without VBA?

Comment: [I would take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335906/return-a-comma-separated-list-from-an-array-formula) question I asked when I started on SO. I was looking to solve a similar problem as you -- it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. It does look like there's some potential there. I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Step 1** : figure out the items need to include for each owner(Grab Items)

In cell G2, put in the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C2)=TRUE,CONCATENATE(C$1,";"),"")
```

Apply it to through G2:J5. This will put the item name in corresponding cell if there is a number in C2:F5

**Step 2** : Concatenate and get list of items:
In cell K2 type in:

```
=CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2)
```

apply it through K2:K5

Comment: Thanks - that does get me there. The real spreadsheet has 42 columns, so the concatenation in step 2 will be long, but doable.

Comment: @abeardneglected yeah, excel's concatenate function does not accept range as input... you might try these methods...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel